# what are the prerequisites to perform mobile testing on sauce labs?

Tags: appium

i am new to Appium. I want to perform mobile testing on android and i OS app using appium tool on sauce labs.

```
I want to know what are the pre-requisites, and how to write the scripts(in java) and how exactly the flow goes.

can anybody help me out??

Thanks a lot in advance.. :-)
```

package com.saucelabs;

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestName;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.URL;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
/**
 * Simple {@link RemoteWebDriver} test that demonstrates how to run your Selenium tests with <a href="http://ondemand.saucelabs.com/ondemand">Sauce OnDemand</a>.
 * *
 * @author Ross Rowe
 */
public class DemoScript {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();

        caps.setCapability("browserName", "");

        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
        caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        caps.setCapability("device-orientation", "portrait");



       /* DesiredCapabilities capabillities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
        capabillities.setCapability("version", "5.0");
        capabillities.setCapability("platform", Platform.MAC);*/
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                      new URL("http://**********************"),caps);
    }

    @Test
    public void basic() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/");
        assertEquals("Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

}

i am new to Appium. I want to perform mobile testing on android and i OS app using appium tool on sauce labs.

I want to know what are the pre-requisites, and how to write the scripts(in java) and how exactly the flow goes.

can anybody help me out??

Thanks a lot in advance.. :-)
```

Are there any changes required in the code?

Is appium server should be started before running the script?

Comment: You did not mention that what error/issue you are getting??

Comment: On executing the above code, it throws "UnreachableBrowserException" Could not start a new session.possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start failure.

Comment: do i have to make ant changes in the code to connect to appium server?if so, Can i have the sample code for the same?

Comment: Do you start appium before run your code? Also do you using default android emulator or any other hardware device?

Comment: ya i am starting the server before running the code. But i am trying to run the code on sauce labs, not on any real device or emulator.